# confusion with chain rule - derivative of scalar by vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I am studying reinforcement learning and came across the following:
[image]

Here $\delta$ is a function of $\theta$.  $\phi$ is independent of $\theta$

I am confused on the third line (annotated with red arrow). Using the following identity:

[image]

In my derivation third line becomes:

$$ -\alpha\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E[\phi\phi^T]^{-1}\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E[\delta\phi](\bigtriangledown_\theta\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E[\delta\phi]) $$

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you missing anything? The expression you've written down is the same expression as the third line in your image but with terms in a different order, no?

Comment: matrix multiplication is not commutative, right? That's why the confusion

Comment: It would help if you put the dimensionality of everything. Like $\delta$ is actually $\delta(\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$?